How can I resolve torch download stop?
I have now connected the Python project to the ec2 instance.
And I ran pip3 install -r requirements.txt on Ubuntu.
But it stopped while downloading the torch module. Doesn't work at 755.1MB.
I am using mac.
Collecting tinycss2==1.2.1
  Downloading tinycss2-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting tomli==2.0.1
  Downloading tomli-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting torch==2.2.2
  Downloading torch-2.2.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (755.5 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╸ 755.1/755.5 MB 30.9 MB/s eta 0:00:01

How can I resolve it?

try pip installing torch on its own and see what happens.

!pip3 install -r requirements.txt

What are the specs of the ec2 instance ? (ram and cpu)
Is the instance working after you stop ?
